# Error in getting user nodes while giving no. of hops as an input using spring with neo4j query

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I am executing the query using spring with neo4j..

```
@Query(value = "START me=node({0}) MATCH me-[:ACTIVEFRIEND*1..{1}]->friend RETURN friend")
public Iterable<User> searchUserInNHops(User a, int hops);
```

where the depth threshold which the search should go is given as an input hops..

It is not working and giving the error..
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: Properties on pattern elements are not allowed in MATCH

Neo4j Version: 1.9.0

I will appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Thanks
Hemant

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the depth as a paramater. If you want this to be dynamic, you might want to consider alternative approaches. Some of them are:

- Let your repository class extend from CypherDslRepository. Use should use the neo4j-cypher-dsl module to build a query object.
- Use the Neo4jTemplate class. You could provide a composed query string to the query method.
- Use the traversal API of Neo4j core, like

Traversal:

```
   for (final Path position : Traversal.description().depthFirst()                    .relationships(RelationType.ACTIVE_FRIEND, Direction.OUTGOING),
       Direction.INCOMING).evaluator(Evaluators.fromDepth(1))
       .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(yourDynamicValue))
       .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition()).traverse(node)) {
       position.endNode();
}
```

Comment: thanks tstorms,,,i will appreciate if you can help me in using neo4j template for such a query n is it possible to from such a query using neo4j template...

Comment: You could use the query method (http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/template/Neo4jOperations.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) which is implemented by the Neo4jTemplate class. As a first argument you provide the CYPHER query as a String, and the second argument could potentionally contain paramaters. You could also provide a null value.

Comment: thanks tstorms..Usiing neo4j Query i executed the query with params...                                                              Result<Map<String, Object>> result = template.query(query, params);
        return result;But then it gave the following error...HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: Expected a propertycontainer or number here, but got: {notifications={"notifications":[]}, status=true

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to post this issue in another question? Consider posting the stacktrace as well.